# Windows 10 wmic path Win32_VideoController error

Tags: cmd.exe

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution,CurrentHorizontalResolution /format:value
```

When I use this code with cmd in 1024x768 resolution in Windows 8, this is output.

[image]

When I use this code with cmd in 1024x768 resolution in Windows 10, this is output.

[image]

Why windows 10 doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you update the question with the output you are seeing now with Windows 10 and if you can, what you had before with Windows 8 or what you are expecting the output to be? Thanks.

Comment: I did as you said

Comment: Does this help - https://serverfault.com/questions/825360/how-to-get-the-screen-resolution-in-windows-10-with-command-prompt-or-powershell

Comment: Sorry, did not you know any other solution?

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative command that is more reliable? Does:
`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms ; "Background {0}x{1}" -f [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize.Height` help?